# IBM i- parse data from IFS text file into a IBM i db2 table?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Is it possible to parse data from IFS text file into a db2 table?  Examples I see use a field in a DB2 table.  In the following example, we use field JDATA from table MYLIB.DATA_IN.

```
INSERT INTO MYLIB.MYTABLE (  value  )
   SELECT value
    FROM MYLIB.DATA_IN, 
    JSON_TABLE (JDATA,'$.meetings[*]'
    COLUMNS (
        value varchar ( 100 ) PATH '$.value'
    )
)
```

Comment: The [CPYFRMSTMF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/cpyfrmstmf.htm) command does what you are describing from the command line or from a CL program.

Comment: What format is the text data in?

Comment: today text file is in JSON.  Mike: good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the format of the text in the IFS file. If you have fixed columns, or delimiter separated values, CPYFRMIMPF will do the trick. If you have a big block of unformatted text that you want to load into a single field database file, CPYFRMSTMF will work. If you have XML or JSON, or HTML, or something else that you want to parse, you will need to do it a different way.

So short answer is YES. No long answer possible without more information.